# C'è una parola in italiano che esprime lo stesso concetto di "capitalization"?

Tags: translation, capitalization

Come da titolo, c'è una parola in italiano che esprime lo stesso concetto di *capitalization*?

Non mi riferisco all'*azione* di assegnare ad ogni lettera del testo (sia esso parola, frase, ...) la forma maiuscola o minuscola, ma alla *proprietà del testo* di avere associata, ad ogni lettera, la *proprietà (della lettera)* di essere maiuscola.

(Immagino tuttavia che, essendo la parola così peculiare, la lingua italiana o ha una parola per entrambi i casi o non ne ha per alcuno.)

Se la parola esistesse e fosse *allegria*, direi che ***Ciao** ha allegria `Mmmm`* (`M`auiscola, `m`inuscola, `m`inuscola, `m`inuscola), o che *CoCcOdRiLlO ha allegria alternata*.

Comment: Per curiosità, sia il dizionario Ragazzini che il sito [“Terminologia etc.”](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2009/02/27/bottoni-e-pulsanti/) di Licia Corbolante propongono “uso delle maiuscole”.

Comment: Credo che un motivo dell'esistenza del termine inglese sia la tradizione, sicuramente viva nel XVIII secolo e oltre, di adoperare la maiuscola per i sostantivi, come ancora si fa in tedesco. Swift la usava e la si può vedere anche nella dichiarazione di indipendenza degli Stati Uniti: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US-original-Declaration-1776.jpg#/media/File:US-original-Declaration-1776.jpg

Comment: Sulla scorta dell'esipodio relativo a _petaloso_ posso provare a proporre _maiuscolazione_...

Comment: Sarebbe una buona occasione per aggiungere una descrizione alla tag "[tag:capitalization]".

Comment: @Enrico più _maiuscolazione_ direi _maiuscolità_ o _maiuscolezza_ :)

Comment: @Enrico: Perché no? Se “maiuscolazione” (o simili) dovesse attecchire e si cominciasse a usare diffusamente, diventerebbe a tutti gli effetti italiano. Ricordo che la storia di “petaloso” è memorabile solo per i fraintendimenti da parte dei giornalisti. Ognuno di noi manipola il linguaggio, crea nuove parole o modifica le esistenti. Senza tanto scalpore, ne sono entrate in uso a centinaia negli ultimi anni e decenni: da molti termini tecnici a “piacione”, dai termini sulla pandemia a, forse “cringiare”.

Comment: @DaG, in principio sono d'accordo, ma a me non piace prima di tutto _capitalization_, in quanto io la interpreterei come l'azione di trasformare _ciao_ in _CIAO_ o, al più, come la proprietà che la scrittura _CIAO_ ha e che _Ciao_ e _ciao_ non hanno. Utilizzare _maiuscolazione_ / _capitalization_ nel modo in cui sarebbe/è usata mi sembra abbia lo stesso problema che ha la frase _Questo canarino e questo cagnolino hanno diverso modo di volare_.

Comment: È interessante il paragone con il “modo di volare”. Se ho ben capito vorresti una sorta di vox media, un po' come “stato civile” detto di una persona (della quale, infatti, non si dice “matrimoniazione” o simili).